# Why might VS2019's Go To Implementation be showing duplicate references?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

The behaviour of the **Go To Implementation** function accessed from the editor context menu or by clicking Ctrl-F12 in Visual Studio has somehow changed in my installation of VS2019.

It used to be that when I used it with the cursor on a method name reference, it would jump directly to the method's implementation unless there were multiple implementations; then it would show them in the **Find Symbol Results** window.

But something has changed and now it always shows the **Find Symbol Results** window even if there is only a single implementation. Furthermore, it shows a duplicate of the single implementation or of each if there are more than one. The screenshot shows this where you can see that the same method definition is listed twice with the same Project, File, Line and Column details.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Could it be some incorrectly cached data causing this? Where might such data be cached? I have cleared my temp files, and deleted contents of folders named `*cache` in any `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0*` folders but this hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Same for me too (for quite some time). Looking forward to an answer from someone 16.11.5 today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplication can be caused when there are more than one `TargetFrameworks` e.g.

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured this out myself and should have answered my own question when I did.

Comment: I totally understand _why_ this is the cause, but VS correctly coalesces/elides duplicates caused by multi-targeting in places like the Error List, Find-all-References and the Call Hierarchy windows, so is there any way to have it filter out dupes for the Go To Implementation results window? (Unfortunately, apparently not...)